# Eliminate from reading ALL collection, allow only a few documents?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

We have a collection with many documents which is the "main" data source of the business.

This collection has a reading rule that makes it *open* for everyone (none users), because that's the purpose of this collection.

I would like to let anyone to *reasonably* read the documents in this collection, which means to **eliminate** a hacker from ***query ALL documents in this collection at once*** just to evaluate the size of my business.

Still, let **none users** (anyone/public) to query multiple documents at once (since some pages requires that, but it's a very small number of documents)

I can't find a rule that let you block a *query for more than* X documents ( let's say 40 ) **in one query.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`request.query.limit`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#query). From the documentation:

```
// Limit documents per request to 50
allow list: if request.query.limit <= 50
```

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that Frank's answer of checking [request.query.limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#query) will limit the size of a single query.  However, checking the limit in rules, doesn't stop the hacker from performing multiple queries using [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query) to get the entire contents of the collection.  It only restricts the value passed to `limit()` in the query.

If you need more control over the types of queries that users can perform, you can use [Cloud Functions HTTP function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) (or some other backend you control) to create an API endpoint for the query, and set security rules to prevent all direct access to the collection.

Comment: thanks a lot. I knew about pagination but was trying to avoid writing a function for that. Can I block the same IP from performing multiple requests, or block some amount of requests within a window of time ?

Comment: There are no IP-based controls for Cloud Firestore.